# React how to pass the id to router using history push

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a page(Course) in that page I am having an card component I am having an hyperlink in that card, once the user is clicking that hyperlink I want to push the data to next page(Edit-Course) along with the ID. I've tried all the ways but when I am pushing the data along with the history, the page is getting navigated but in the url I am not getting the ID, it's not getting append in the URL. Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
          **Path.js**
            
               course: {
          root: path(ROOTS.app, '/management/course/'),
          courses: path(ROOTS.app, '/management/course/'),
          newCourse: path(ROOTS.app, '/management/course/new-course'),
    
       This is the page I am trying to navigate with ID   
     editCourse: path(ROOTS.app, '/management/course/editCourse/:id?'),

        },
    
  **CourseItem.js**

      const { cover, title, view, comment, share, author, createdAt, id } = course;
             
     const handleEditCourse = () => {
        history.push(PATH_APP.management.course.editCourse + '${id}');
        history.push(PATH_APP.management.course.editCourse / '${id}'); when I am trying with slan I am getting Nan Error
      };
            
                 <Box sx={{ typography: 'caption', color: 'text.disabled', mb: 1 }}>
                        {fDate(createdAt)}
                      </Box>
            
                      <Link
                        color="inherit"
                        variant="subtitle2"
                        component={RouterLink}
                        onClick={handleEditCourse}
                        className={classes.cardTitle}
                      >
                        {title}
                      </Link>
                 </cardContent>
```

Comment: what's the URL you're redirected to exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

```
history.push(`${PATH_APP.management.course.editCourse}/${id}`);
```

do it like that. use template literal

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried that too, when I am trying that I am getting the output like below 

/app/management/course/editCourse/:id?/49  id getting updated like this

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved the output by using below method. I am having an root for all the path which I am creating in project , instead of directly accessing the path I accessed via root like below

```
const handleEditCourse = () => {
    history.push(PATH_APP.management.course.root + 'editCourse/' + `${id}`);
  };
```

I am getting the expected output. Thanks all!